# Using python to edit html, but lxml converts nice html entities to strange encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding, html-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to use python (with pyquery and lxml) to alter and clean up some html.

```
Eg. html = "<div><!-- word style><bleep><omgz 1,000 tags><--><p>It&#146;s a spicy meatball!</div>"
```

The lxml.html.clean function, clean_html(), works well, except that it replaces the nice html entities like

```
&#146;
```

with some unicode string

```
\xc2\x92
```

The unicode looks strange in different browsers (firefox and opera using auto encoding, utf8, latin-1, etc), like an empty box.  How can I stop lxml converting the entities?  How can I get it all in latin-1 encoding?  Seems strange that a module built specifically for html would do this.

I can't be sure of which characters are there, so I can't just use

```
replace("\xc2\x92","&#146;").
```

I've tried using

```
clean_html(html).encode('latin-1')
```

but the unicode persists.

And yes, I'd tell people to stop using word to write html, but then I'd hear the whole

> "iz th wayz i liks it u cant mak me chang hitlr".

Edit: a beautifulsoup solution:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(desc[desc_type]))
                    comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
                    [comment.extract() for comment in comments]
                    print soup
```

Comment: Curious: Why aren't you using BeautifulSoup

Comment: @inspector: As I understand it, BeautifulSoup is no longer under active development, and users are encouraged to seek other solutions (such as lxml).

Answer (score 12):

There are a few things that - if you know them - will lead to the easiest/best solution:

- `clean_html()` returns the same type you provide it with: if you give it a string, it will return a string, but if you give it an Element or ElementTree, it will return an Element or ElementTree respectively
- you can control the way an Element or ElementTree is serialized, by giving encoding options to `lxml.html.tostring()` method or the tree's `write()` method (same goes for xml by the way). You can do this with `encoding='utf-8'` for example.
- any content that CAN be encoded in that encoding, will be output as an encoded string, any content that cannot will be "escaped" as entities. Using `encoding="ascii"` will force any non-ascii characters to "nice" entities like you wish.

Put together, this means: first parse the string into an element (or tree if you wish), clean it, and serialize it as needed:

```
html = lxml.html.fromstring("<div><!-- word style><bleep><omgz 1,000 tags><--><p>It&#146;s a spicy meatball!</div>")
html = clean_html(html)
result = lxml.html.tostring(html, encoding="ascii")
```

(and a slightly dirtier trick is to use the errors parameter on the `encode()` method of a unicode string: try encoding a unicode string containing "special" characters with `s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` and see what that does...)

Answer (score 2):

I assume `&#146;` is supposed to be a quotation mark. The str object with byte value 146, `chr(146)`, decoded with `cp1252` is a quotation mark:

```
In [46]: print(chr(146).decode('cp1252'))
’
```

So, you could do this:

```
import lxml.html.clean as clean
import re

html = "<div><!-- word style><bleep><omgz 1,000 tags><--><p>It&#146;s a spicy meatball!</div>"

html=re.sub('&#(\d+);',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))).decode('cp1252'),html)
print(html)
# <div><!-- word style><bleep><omgz 1,000 tags><--><p>It’s a spicy meatball!</div>
print(type(html))
# <type 'unicode'>
print(clean.clean_html(html))
# <div><p>It’s a spicy meatball!</p></div>
```

Or,

```
doc=lh.fromstring(html)
clean.clean(doc)
```

Note that the quotation mark has unicode code point value 8217. That is, `ord(chr(146).decode('cp1252'))` equals 8217, so `lh.tostring` returns:

```
print(lh.tostring(doc))
# <div><p>It&#8217;s a spicy meatball!</p></div>
```

You could re-encode it in cp1252 like this:

```
print(repr(lh.tostring(doc,encoding='cp1252')))
# '<div><p>It\x92s a spicy meatball!</p></div>'
```

I don't know how to coax lxml to return

```
'<div><p>It&#146;s a spicy meatball!</p></div>'
```

to match the output of your BeautifulSoup code, however. Well, clearly it could be done with regex (reversing what I did above), but I don't know if that is necessary or advisable, since lxml should already be returning html that other applications can understand.

```
result=re.sub('&#(\d+);',lambda m: '&#{n};'.format(
    n=ord(unichr(int(m.group(1))).encode('cp1252'))),
            lh.tostring(doc))
print(result)
# <div><p>It&#146;s a spicy meatball!</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just convert the utf8 string into ascii with xml characters

```
result = result.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```