# How to prevent lxml from converting '&' character to '&amp;'?

Tags: python, lxml

I need to send the control characters `&#x0D;` and `&#x0A;` in my XML file so that the text is displayed correctly in the target system.

For the creation of the XML file I use the lxml library. This is my attempt:

```
from lxml import etree as et
import lxml.builder

e = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()

xml_doc = e.newOrderRequest(
    e.Orders(
        e.Order(
            e.OrderNumber('12345'),
            e.OrderID('001'),
            e.Articles(
                e.Article(
                    e.ArticleNumber('000111'),
                    e.ArticleName('Logitec Mouse'),
                    e.ArticleDescription('* 4 Buttons&#x0D;&#x0A;* 600 DPI&#x0D;&#x0A;* Bluetooth')
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

tree = et.ElementTree(xml_doc)
tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

This is the result:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<newOrderRequest>
  <Orders>
    <Order>
      <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
      <OrderID>001</OrderID>
      <Articles>
        <Article>
          <ArticleNumber>000111</ArticleNumber>
          <ArticleName>Logitec Mouse</ArticleName>
          <ArticleDescription>* 4 Buttons&amp;#x0D;&amp;#x0A;* 600 DPI&amp;#x0D;&amp;#x0A;* Bluetooth</ArticleDescription>
        </Article>
      </Articles>
    </Order>
  </Orders>
</newOrderRequest>
```

This is what I need:

```xml
<ArticleDescription>* 4 Buttons&#x0D;&#x0A;* 600 DPI&#x0D;&#x0A;* Bluetooth</ArticleDescription>
```

Is there a function in the lxml library to turn off the conversion or does anyone know a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's the same problem, but does this answer your question? [Using python to edit html, but lxml converts nice html entities to strange encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876716/using-python-to-edit-html-but-lxml-converts-nice-html-entities-to-strange-encod)

Comment: Don't assign a Python string _with the data pre-escaped_; instead, assign a string with the data _unescaped_ and let the escaping convert it into the correct form. Tools that work the way you're asking for are a source of serious security problems: injecting data without escaping is the source of, well, injection attacks. Assign the _real_ string, not the HTML-ized one, and everything will work perfectly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy

Normally I would expect the system to correctly interpret an Enter as a new line, which unfortunately it does not. If I edit the control characters manually in the XML file and the target system imports them that way, everything is displayed correctly. It is exasperating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the Python script:

```py
import lxml.etree as et
print(repr(et.fromstring('''<ArticleDescription>* 4 Buttons&#x0D;&#x0A;* 600 DPI&#x0D;&#x0A;* Bluetooth</ArticleDescription>''').text))
```

...is...

```
'* 4 Buttons\r\n* 600 DPI\r\n* Bluetooth'
```

That means that the Python-syntax way to write the XML-syntax string `* 4 Buttons&#x0D;&#x0A;* 600 DPI&#x0D;&#x0A;* Bluetooth` is as `'* 4 Buttons\r\n* 600 DPI\r\n* Bluetooth'`.

Thus, the relevant line of code should be:

```
e.ArticleDescription('* 4 Buttons\r\n* 600 DPI\r\n* Bluetooth')
```

...and if the consumer doesn't treat the resulting output as *exactly identical to* `import lxml.etree as et print(repr(et.fromstring('''<ArticleDescription>* 4 Buttons&#x0D;&#x0A;* 600 DPI&#x0D;&#x0A;* Bluetooth</ArticleDescription>`, that consumer is broken.

See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/ImportantClassicConversion#test.py running your code with the modification suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a python or lxml issue - it is how XML parsers and serializers work.
If you want to use a specific character in your programming language, then make it that character. The serializer will convert it into an entity reference if required, and the parser will convert it back when reading the document. You cannot turn it off - it would be against the specification.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax:
*The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` " respectively.*

An exception might be to use a CDATA section as explained in [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)